# Web3JS Send Transaction

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm quite new Web3 and Solidity development. Trying work on my first DAPP just to learn more about this world. I'm using metamask and I'm also getting no errors in the browser. I'm doing a send transaction and the result is not popping up in the console but there is no error as well. Please help me improve on my code and guide me in the right direction.

```
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8545");

async function requestWeb3() {
    await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
}

requestWeb3();

let account;

const contractABI = [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "buyAd",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "lastPrice",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

const contractAddress = "0x933ef849cca1c037c5b335ce5ea1c309a6de6d67";

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
    console.log(accounts[0]);
    accounts = accounts;
})


const connectBtn = document.getElementById("connect");

connectBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('click');
    contract.methods.buyAd().send({
        from:accounts[0],
        to:contractAddress,
        value:  "1000000000000000000", 
        data: "0xdf"
        }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error!", err);
                return
            }
            console.log(result);
        
    })
});
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract AdvertisementAuction {
    
    uint public lastPrice = 0;
    
    function buyAd() payable public {
        require(msg.value > lastPrice, "This advertisement costs more then the inputed value.");
        lastPrice = msg.value;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this script:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const ethEnabled = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

We check if `window.ethereum` exists, then create a `window.web3` object with our own version of web3, using the window.ethereum object as the input provider.
In this case, the `await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts')` function calls the pop-up UI dialogue that asks the user’s permission to connect the dApp to MetaMask.

It should works. Let me know :)